# Add a read-only deployment key to a heroku instance

Tags: heroku

I'm deploying a Go project, and it's `go get ./...` stage fails, because the repository is private and the heroku instance doesn't have the valid private keys to pull it.

Is it possible to add a private read-only deployment key (e.g. bitbucket) to a heroku instance?

If I'd add it to the buildpack itself, it would be exposed to everyone since buildpacks are public repos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [Heroku Labs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs) feature called [`user-env-compile`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile) that allows your app's config vars to be available at compile time. If you have this enabled, you can add your deployment key with `heroku config:add KEY=VALUE` and then have your buildpack read the value at compile from the environment. Since all of your app's config will be available, make sure you are using a trustworthy buildpack. For more information about this feature, see the Dev Center article:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile